# Table of 4 columns "definition is too large"

Tags: mysql, myisam

I'm trying to optimize a large(4M rows) and busy table of mine. It's currently

```sql
CREATE TABLE `person_search` (
    `token` CHAR(63), -- each word of the person's name
    `person_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED, -- foreign key on person.id; not constrained because MyiSAM
    `birth_date` DATE NULL, -- for ordering the results
    `gender` ENUM('male', 'female') NULL, -- additional filtering
    INDEX (`token`, `birth_date`, `person_id`),
    INDEX (`person_id`, `token`)
) ENGINE='MyISAM';
```

Searches are performed by `INNER JOIN`ing this table with itself as many times as needed for the number of tokens in the user's query. (For performance, searches are always prefix searches (`LIKE 'foo%'`); not sub-string searches (`LIKE '%foo%'`)).

To potentially improve performance, I tried `MODIFY`ing the token column to be a massive `ENUM()`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `person_search` MODIFY `token` ENUM(
    'AAB',
    'AABYE',
    'AACH',
    -- snip ~110'000 values; longest value is 20 chars
    'ZYSTRA',
    'ZYWYLO',
    'ZYZAK'
) NOT NULL;
```

but after a few seconds, MySQL returned the error `ERROR 1117 (HY000): Table definition is too large`. [Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+%22Table+definition+is+too+large%22) didn't help.

I think MySQL/MyiSAM can't do this, and I'll have to handle the enumeration myself in the application instead of the DB, or make a person_search_token_enum table and add more `inner join`s.

But maybe I'm missing a setting or something. It's not a shared server; I can make any configuration changes I want.

Comment: Recomend (*) use `VARCHAR` (*) use InnoDB. (*) not use enum for so many options.

Answer (score 2):

Read this in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

> An ENUM column can have a maximum of 65,535 distinct elements.

This data type enumerates values using either an 8-bit integer or a 16-bit integer. That number of bits can enumerate at most 2<sup>16</sup> distinct values.

That explains the error you encountered.

It seems like your attempt to optimize is very similar to [fulltext indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html). You should read that section of the manual and see if it does what you want, probably more efficiently and much easier to implement.